# What is syntax for "options" in Doctrine 2.1 @Column annotation?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to define a column in Doctrine 2.1 (using annotations) that maps to a fixed length CHAR column in MySQL. Using fixed=true doesn't do the job. The annotation

```
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=49, fixed=true, nullable=false)
```

it results in an error: "The annotation @ORM\Column declared on property [name here] does not have a property named "fixed". Available properties: name, type, length, precision, scale, unique, nullable, options, columnDefinition". So I'm assuming that the "fixed" bit needs to be passed in "options". But how? I've scoured the Doctrine 2.1 documentation and cannot find anything on this.

I tried

```
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=49, options="fixed=true", nullable=false)
```

which doesn't result in an error, but is ignored -- the column created is VARCHAR (49).

I'd prefer not to use columnDefinition.

Any suggestions?

THANKS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=49, options={"fixed":true}, nullable=false)
```

Comment: Someone tell me why this is such a secret information to find. The question being two years old... exactly when I needed the information, God sent Patrick here only 16 hours ago to share this to me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a FIXED data type to your annotations will require a user-defined function in Doctrine. The [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs) on how to set these up is pretty readable.

There is also a library of MySQL query functions in Benjamin Eeberlei's [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql) repository that you might find helpful for extending the native capabilities of Doctrine to accommodate MySQL-specific features.

Unfortunately it doesn't include the data type you're looking for, but it may be helpful as a model for setting up what you need. Good luck and please post if you find a solution that works for you.