# What's the syntax for 'fixed' option, in Doctrine XML schema files?

Tags: doctrine-orm

This is very similar to another question concerning [how to switch a type from 'varchar' to 'char'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903404/what-is-syntax-for-options-in-doctrine-2-1-column-annotation). However, I'm having trouble getting my XML config to work.

One of the fields that `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` is saying differs from my database is this:

```
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE password password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL;
```

I'm pretty certain that that's because my database definition for that field is correctly set to `char(32)`, but Doctrine isn't expecting the field to be fixed.

To poke Doctrine into knowing it's fixed, I've added the following XML:

```
<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="32" nullable="false">
    <options>
        <option name="fixed" value="true" />
    </options>
</field>
```

Is this not correct?

Some bonus information, if it matters: I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stumbled upon on your thread.

The syntax in your original post was incorrect. I wanted to leave my comment just in-case someone else happens to find this thread. While the accepted answer works, the 'fixed option' in the Doctrine schema works too.

With the code snipet above, it should look like this:

```
<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="32" nullable="false">
    <options>
        <option name="fixed">true</option>
    </options>
</field>
```

The attribute value is not valid.

Hope this helps whoever ventures on this thread!

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon a reasonable enough answer, but it's definitely a bit of a hack.

`<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="32" nullable="false" column-definition="CHAR(32) NOT NULL" />`

`length` and `nullable` are actually ignored here, but I figured I'd leave them in the be verbose about what I want. The `column-definition` is actually what's forcing the fixed length CHAR.

Unfortunately, this attribute doesn't seem to get taken into account when doing the schema diff, so it'll always say there's a difference on that field.